Confused about one detail on proof relating 'two-sided' limits with one-sided limits
I am reading this proof which proves the following theorem:

$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \iff \lim\limits_{x \to c-} f(x) = L$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to c+} f(x) = L$

Here is my understanding so far for proving the $\Rightarrow$ case:
We have the following property

$0 < |x-c| < \delta \iff c - \delta < x < c ~~~ \text{OR}~~~ c < x < c + \delta$

which when combined with the delta epsilon definition of a limit and the given $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ , will lead to:

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0$ :
$c - \delta < x < c  \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon ~~~\text{OR}~~~ c < x < c + \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

which is equivalent to:

$\lim\limits_{x \to c-} f(x) = L~~~\text{OR}~~~\lim\limits_{x \to c+} f(x) = L$

But where I am confused is how we go from OR to AND since we are trying to prove that both the right hand side AND the left hand side limit exists. Did I go wrong somewhere with what I have so far or what am I missing?

"p or q implies r" is equivalent to "p implies r and q implies r"

@MichalAdamaszek thank you for the comment, to make sure i understand what you are saying, do you mean (p or q) -> r = (p -> r) and (q -> r)? However, can you elaborate on what p and q is in this case? I assume R is that both left hand and right hand side limits exist?

Here's my own version of the $\Rightarrow$ case of the proof based on what's been said in this thread so far. It might be verbose but I'm just trying to make things super clear for anyone reading this in the future.
Goal: Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to c-} f(x) = L ~~\text{and}~~\lim\limits_{x \to c+} = L$
Recall the following definitions:

Suppose f(x) is defined on an interval (a,b) where a < b:
$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: 0 < |x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < 0 \\
\lim\limits_{x \to c+} f(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: c < x < c + \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L|<\epsilon \\
\lim\limits_{x \to c-} f(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: c - \delta < x < c \Rightarrow |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

We will also use the following properties:

$\text{[1]}~~0<|x-c| < \delta \iff (c - \delta < x < c)~~ \lor ~~(c < x < c + \delta) \\
\text{[2]} ~~(p \lor q) \Rightarrow r \equiv (p \Rightarrow r) \land (q \Rightarrow r)$

Because of [1]:
$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: 0 < |x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < 0 \\
\rightsquigarrow  \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: [(c - \delta < x < c)~~ \lor ~~(c < x < c + \delta)] \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < 0 \\ $
Then because of [2] where $p = c - \delta < x < c$ and $q = c < x < c + \delta$ and $r = |f(x) - L| < 0$:
$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon, ~ \exists \delta: (c - \delta < x < c \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < 0)~~ \land ~~(c < x < c + \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < 0) \\ $
Which finally by definition of left handed and right handed limits leads to:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to c-} f(x) = L ~~\text{and}~~\lim\limits_{x \to c+} = L$$

If $\lim\limits_{x\ \to c}f(x)=L$, there are two possibilities:
$1):$ $(c-\delta<x<c) \implies \lim\limits_{x \to \ c^{-}}f(x)=L$ $\quad$
$2):$ $(c<x<c+\delta) \implies \lim\limits_{x \to \ c^{+}}f(x)=L$ $\quad$
Conversely, to show $1)$ or $2)$ $\implies \lim\limits_{x\ \to c}f(x)=L,$ it is equivalent to
$1)$ $\implies \lim\limits_{x\ \to c}f(x)=L$ $\textbf{and}$ $ $$2)$ $\implies \lim\limits_{x\ \to c}f(x)=L$, which means $\lim\limits_{x\to\ c}f(x)=\begin{cases} \lim\limits_{x\ \to c^{-}}f(x), & \text{if $c-\delta<x<c$} \\ \lim\limits_{x\to\ c^{+}}f(x), & \text{if $c<x<c+\delta$}\end{cases}$
Reason: $p\vee q \implies r $ $\quad$$\Longleftrightarrow$ $\quad$ $(p\implies r) \wedge(q \implies r)$

Thank you for the answer, I think I worked it out. I am curious, where did you learn the rule (p or q) -> r and (p -> r) and (q -> r) are equivalent? I don't have an advanced math background and self studying calculus.

@SarahAnderson Maybe you will learn it in discrete mathematics.
